# Monte Carlo integration help needed

Tags: r, monte-carlo, numerical-integration

I'm trying to simulate these two integrals using Monte Carlo simulation:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2) dx, \quad \mbox{and } \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-|x|) dx . 
$$

When I use `runif(n,-Inf,Inf)`, I get `NaN` (number very close to zero) (using R).
I also tried converting that to a polar coordinates integral ($drdθ$ integral) but then I don't really know how to do the double integration needed.

Any ideas?

Comment: The integral for $exp(-x^2)$ using polar coordinates is relatively easy if you work with the square of the integral $I^2 = \int exp(-x^2)dx.\int exp(-y^2)dy$; - write as a double integral, convert to polar (use $x^2+y^2=r^2$ along the way), don't forget the Jacobian, and you should be set.

Comment: I already tried that, but I'm stuck at how to do a double integration in R, not on paper

Comment: Oh. In that case (that you want to do the double integral numerically) I think the conversion to polar coordinates may not be the best choice (though the [polar method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) for generating normal random variables is one of two methods that does use polar coordinates, and so could form the basis for such a method of working out that integral)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For suitably large $a>0$, you can sample from a $\mathrm{U}[-a,a]$ distribution because, for these two integrals, since the "tails" of the functions decay fast enough, $\int_{-\infty}^{-a} f(x)\,dx + \int_{a}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is small. Don't forget to normalize the uniform density properly. For comparison, here are the analytical results and the corresponding simulations.

$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi} \approx 1.772454
$$

```
N <- 10^6
a <- 5
(2*a) * sum(exp(-(runif(N, -a, a)^2))) / N
[1] 1.77192
```

$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}\,dx = 2
$$

```
(2*a) * sum(exp(-abs(runif(N, -a, a)))) / N
[1] 1.988736
```

Comment: So you use the uniform distribution but in the range of (-5,5), but still get the correct result ?
Could you explain that please ?

Comment: I see.
But how come I get worse results if I even make that range (-6,6) ? 
The result diverges greatly. What makes (-5,5) the right one ?

Also, is there a way to make a graph of this simulation (of what it does in every step, I guess)?

Comment: It doesn't diverge: `N <- 10^6; 12 * sum(exp(-(runif(N, -6, 6)^2))) / N` gives `1.775803` for example. You probably didn't adjust the normalization constant of the density when you went from $[-5,5]$ to $[-6,6]$. That $10$ must become $12$.

Comment: Although you are correct, your reasoning is not: the smallness of the integrand outside any finite interval does not guarantee that it can be ignored outside that interval!

Comment: Awesome. 
It's just that as a mathematician, this (-5,5) seemed weird.
I get it now with the alphas.

Thanks a lot.
Any idea about the graph ? I tried running the function for some N's with a for loop and a dotplot from lattice, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

According with runif manual page which you can find [here](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/Uniform.html), the min and max parameter values must be finite. If not it will produce NAs.

Comment: This is an example of a poorly written code. It should have raised an exception or better a fatal error when called with Inf argument instead of silently returning NaN.

Comment: @Aksakal Have you made this suggestion to the R developers?

Comment: @Aksakal `runif(1,-Inf, Inf)` gives a warning and the documentation says that the limits must be finite. I prefer this to an error and this is consistend behavior in R.

Comment: @user777, R developers are not real programmers. It's a waste of time to preach good coding practice to non programmers

Answer (score 4):

Uniform distribution is not defined on unbounded domain. It has to be $[-\infty<a<x<b<\infty]$.

That was your main issue. The second issue is that when you integrate with MC you don't have to use uniform distribution. Your case is a good example of when not to use it, in fact. Look up [importance sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration#Importance_sampling_algorithm) subject in any Monte Carlo tutorial. Obviously, normal or exponential distributions would be good places to start for your integrals.

In a nutshell, what you're doing is this: $\hat{I}=\sum_if(x_i)/p(x_i)$, where $p(x_i)$ is the  PDF of your sampling distribution. In the most basic case it would uniform distribution, i.e. $\frac{1}{b-a}$. If you use normal distribution it'll be $\frac{e^{-x_i^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

UPDATE:
The MATLAB code would be like this:

```
x=randn(10000,1);
mean(exp(-x.^2)./normpdf(x))

ans =

    1.7828
```

Comment: So, I tried using rnorm and I get this:
 

    > f=function(n){
    + x=rnorm(n)
    + g=exp(-x^2)
    + f=mean(g)
    + f
    + }
    > 
    > f(10000)
    [1] 0.5800912

but using "integrate", I get this:

    > f <- function(x) {exp(-x^2)}
    > integrate(f,-Inf,Inf)
    1.772454 with absolute error < 4.3e-06

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: @integral, try using code markup so that we can read your code.

Comment: Can't get `code` to work properly.
Here is a pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/RKDLNbJa

Comment: integral `code` markup works in questions and answers. Comments are not designed to hold chunks of code - if it's too long for the `inline` backquoted (\`inline-code\`) markup, put it at the bottom of your question via an edit.

Comment: @integral, you didn't implement sampling right. Particularly, the change of measure part, i.e. where you divide by PDF.